# Reading a line from a text file and splitting its contents

Tags: java

So this is my text file:

> CareFlight101      0     2
>
> PiperCub           2     99
>
> AirAmbulance       2     1
>
> TransWorld122      2     5
>
> Cessna152          3     99
>
> Eastern429         4     10

They are suppose to be aircrafts name followed my arrival time and landing priority.

I am trying to splitting it so that it takes each into account. I am having trouble splitting it though because it it throwing a 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1' error
This is what I have so far:

```
public class TheAircrafts {

    public static ArrayList<Plane> planeList;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            File f = new File("sample_data_p3.txt");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

            List<Plane> people = new ArrayList<Plane>();

            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                String[] details = line.split("\\s+");
                String flightID = details[0];
                int arrivalTime = Integer.parseInt(details[1]);
                int landingPriority = Integer.parseInt(details[2]);
                Plane p = new Plane(flightID, arrivalTime, landingPriority);
                planeList.add(p);
            }

            for(Plane p: planeList){
                System.out.println(p.toString());
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And in my plane class I have:

```
public class Plane {

    private String flightID;
    private int arrivalTime;
    private int landingPriority;
    private int numRunways;


    public Plane(String flightID, int arrivalTime, int landingPriority) {
            this.setflightID(flightID); 
            this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
            this.landingPriority = landingPriority; 
    }
```

followed by get and set and get methods for each of the variables

Comment: use `if (details.length==3) {` before reading flightId and other stuff. You should also debug this issue to see what is the input lne

Answer (score 0):

You get a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in this case when there is a line which not more than `i` elements seperated by a space.

In your case there is a line which has only **one word** in it. And hence when you try to get the second word which **didn't exist** you get an Exception.

To avoid getting so, you can check if that line has `3` words or not.

```
String []details = line.split("\\s+");
if(details.length == 3)
{
 //do your setting
}
```